# Cesium Dynamic updating of entities from external data stream

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm a total noob at Cesium so forgive me for any stupidity. I'm trying to write an application that streams position and orientation data to Cesium, where it is plotted in real time along with a path showing where it's been. I'm having an issue where there is visual stuttering of the entity, almost certainly caused by the fact that the entity.position property is being updated faster than the draw call can execute. I was having the same issue with the path polyline, but found a code snippet that fixed it for me:

```
var pathtrace = new Cesium.PolylineCollection();

primitives = viewer.scene.primitives;

var objpath = pathtrace.add({
name : 'Path',
polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([0, 0, 0,
                                                            0, 0, 0])
    }
});
primitives.add(pathtrace);

...Inside loop...

data = JSON.parse(result.data);
objpos = data.concat(objpos);
objpath.positions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(objpos);
```

However, I have been unable to find anything with the same functionality as PolylineCollection for optimizing the entity for dynamic updating. Right now I'm using:

```
var vehicle = viewer.entities.add({
    name : "Vehicle",
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(0, 0),
    orientation : orientation,
    model : {
        url : url,
        minimumPixelSize : 50
    }
});

...Inside loop...

vehicle.position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
```

...which is resulting in the entity jumping back and forth as it moves. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use `callbackProperty`. Something like this:

```js
// init somewhere
var vehiclesPositions = {}; 

// when you parse the data for each vhicle
... init loop ...
let vhicle = vhicles[i]; // use let to make sure vhicle is always the same for this loop scope
vehiclesPositions[vhicle.id] = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(vhicle.longitude, vhicle.latitude);
    
var vehicle = viewer.entities.add({
    name : "Vehicle",
    // I can't cover all of the issues that might arise with the scope here. See note for the let vhicle line
    position : new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function() { return vehiclesPositions[vhicle.id]; },
    orientation : orientation,
    model : {
        url : url,
        minimumPixelSize : 50
    }
});
```

... end init loop ...

Then you do the update loop:

... in update loop ...

```js
// I assume you get the right ID somehow
vehiclesPositions[vhicle.id] = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
```

... end update loop ...

Then you should stop see the stutter.

Comment: So instead of giving a property value directly, you give a callback function which will constantly be re-evaluated lazily, as-needed. That is the purpose of [`Cesium.CallbackProperty`](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/CallbackProperty.html). ./